# Automated browsing of complicated web pages

Tags: webkit, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I have a project that will involve heavy automation of complicated web pages.

I realize there are Mechanize and Beautiful Soup, but don't these break when dealing with large amounts of DOM scripting and other weird stuff you find on complicated web pages?

I think I want essentially a barebones running instance of WebKit that allows me to either do "GUI scripting" or access the DOM.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Sahi with PhantomJS. Sahi is a browser automation tool, and PhantomJS is a headless Webkit browser. You can find set-up instructions here: http://sahi.co.in/w/sahi-headless-execution-with-phantomjs

Disclaimer: We created the Sahi product.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that Sahi is your product and this may bias your recommendation.

Comment: Thanks again James for pointing this out. I have edited the answer to indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you working on? And what language do you intend to use?

Adobe Air let's you embed a webkit inside an Air application and interact with the page JavaScript (there is two-way communication between the page JS and the AIR runtime).

Otherwise, if you are not bound to webkit you could take Mozilla Chromeless for a spin.

My apologies if none of this does what you need to do, I can't quite figure what exactly you are trying to do (page scraping? submitting forms?).

Answer (score 0):

For testing/scraping i would try:

- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org)
- [EnvJS](http://www.envjs.com)
- [Windmill](http://www.getwindmill.com)
- [Watir](http://watir.com)
- [Sahi](http://sahi.co.in/w/)
- [WebTest](http://www.canoo.com/webexperts/products/webtest/)